# Not getting friends comment data in Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I am using Graph API for fetching Facebook data including posts, friends etc. While retrieving posts, I am only getting the comments made by the post admin not his friends'. 
My app is in development mode, the user which was used for testing have been added as a Developer in the app. A friend of the post admin tried logging in, granted permissions to access and then liked and commented on the post. but still not getting their data. Any idea?

Comment: What permissions where granted by who exactly? What kind of post are we talking about, on a user profile or a page?

Comment: @misorude, it is a user profile post. Every permission related to user is granted

Comment: Again, by _who_?

Comment: Not sure if that is supposed to work in dev mode. Facebook has limited what is available in that mode, so that it doesn’t get abused to provide functionality outside the control of app review.

Comment: which means we will get only the comments posted by the post admin. correct?

Comment: It is extremely hard to find accurate information on that in the docs, so I couldn’t tell you for sure.